# Missing build folder with concourse cloud foundry resource

Tags: concourse

I have a pipeline that the gets a repo (project-src) and does a build on the repo (project-src) folder.

The build creates another directory in the project-src folder. The problem is when I PUT that project-src folder using the cloud foundry resource the new folder is not pushed up. Here's my code:

```
resources:
- name: project-src
  type: git
  source:
    uri: {{uri}}
    branch: {{branch}}
    private_key: {{key}}

- name: deploy-cloud-foundry
  type: cf
  source:
    api: {{api}}
    username: {{username}}
    password: {{password}}
    organization: {{organization}}
    space: {{space}}

jobs:
- name: build-job
  plan:
  - get: project-src
  - task: build-it
    file: project-src/ci/tasks/build.yml
  - put: deploy-to-cf
    params:
      manifest: project-src/manifest.yml
```

Contents of build.yml:

```
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: dtest, tag: "2" }

inputs:
- name: project-src

run:
  path: ./ci/scripts/build.sh //this creates a folder in project-src
  dir: project-src
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the put is run in a separate container than the build task. Therefore I would need to copy the entire project-src directory to say for example project-src-built and make this an output of the build-it task

Answer (score 1):

As you said the put is in fact run in a separate container and the contents of project-src do need to be an output of the build task.

Comment: Hmmm, still doesn't seem to work. I copied the repo folder to build-src, in the /tmp/build/fa52b501 folder so I now have /tmp/build/fa52b501/repo and /tmp/fa52b501/build-src, I then created an output called build-src, and put this as an input to the cf resource, but the cf resource is always looking in  /tmp/build/put/built-src, any ideas?